# Arrow keys keyboard navigation with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In Jquery I would like to know how to trigger/click an a href... link that's within a .php page. This page is dynamically generating two links that I'd like to trigger using left and right keyboard arrow keys for paging next and back through a site. The links are two images within two divs. I attempted to use [this](http://designshack.co.uk/tutorialexamples/keyboardnavigation/index.html) but was unable to get to work due to how the links are being created.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I could do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402698/binding-arrow-keys-in-js-jquery/1402733#1402733):

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
       alert( "left pressed" );
       return false;
    }
});
```

Character codes:

37 - left

38 - up

39 - right

40 - down

Answer (score 3):

```
$('a').trigger('click');
```

Comment: I tried...

$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
       $("#next").trigger('click');
    }
});

To trigger a link formatted similar to below...

<a accesskey='n' href='URL'><img src='URL.gif' alt='Next >' title='Next >' id='next' /></a>

...and not having any luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Derek: try putting the id #next in the A tag instead of the IMG tag.

Comment: @David Thanks for the help. Unfortunately I'm still unable to trigger a link via arrow keys after changing the location of the ID to the A tag. The code @jbochi shared works for displaying an alert, I'm just not able to figure out how to get this script to select and trigger a link.