# jQuery arrow key binding ( webbrowser class IE )

Tags: jquery, activex, webbrowser-control, keydown

I have an application which uses the microsoft webbrowser class ( IE activex ).
I'm trying to bind the keydown event and add custom control to the arrow keys, but the keydown event is not fired when using the arrow keys.

I tried following code to capture the keydown event:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){   
alert("keydown");  });

$("#element").keydown(function(e){   
alert("keydown");  });

document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
  evt = evt || window.event;
  var keyCode = evt.keyCodeq
  if (keyCode >= 37 && keyCode <= 40) {
      alert("ok");
      return false;
  }
};
```

The keydown event works, delete key by example, but not when using the arrow keys.
When I use the arrow keys in the activex browser, the document scrolls, but it's not possible to add custom control.

In regular IE (non activex) everything works fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402698/binding-arrow-keys-in-js-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is nothing to do much.

1.

```
<input type="text" id="test_element">
```

2.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
 $("#test_element").keydown(function(e){
  switch(e.which){
   case 37: movement = 'left'; break;
   case 38: movement = 'up'; break;
   case 39: movement = 'down'; break;
   case 40: movement = 'right'; break;
   default: movement = false; break;
  }
  if(movement){
    alert("You just clicked "+movement+" arrow key");
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is correct, when I use regular IE

When I call my webpage in the webbrowser control (activex) and I use the arrow keys in #test_element nothing happens

Example: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/399104/screenshots/2011-03-10_1041.swf 

First screen = IE8 
Second screen = webbrowser control in my application