# Detecting arrow key presses in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, keypress, keyboard-events

How do I detect when one of the arrow keys are pressed? I used this to find out:

```
function checkKey(e) {
    var event = window.event ? window.event : e;
    console.log(event.keyCode)
}
```

Though it worked for every other key, it didn't for arrow keys (maybe because the browser is supposed to scroll on these keys by default).

Answer (score 938, accepted):

Arrow keys are only triggered by `onkeydown`, not `onkeypress`.

The keycodes are:

- left = 37
- up  = 38
- right = 39
- down = 40

Comment: Some browsers do trigger `keypress` events for arrow keys, but you're right that `keydown` always works for arrow keys.

Comment: If you press %, you also get keyCode 37

Comment: @xorcus -- No, you get `53` with a `keydown` event.  You get `37` with `keypress`, which is a different thing

Comment: @1nfiniti onkeyup won't consider the repeated call of the keydown event when you hold the arrow down.

Comment: :( arrow key presses not being visible on "keypress" puts serious limitations. You practically can't do things like "if (evt.which === 40) { itemIndex +=1; scrollToFunction(...);" on "keypress" - which should keep scrolling as long as you don't take your finger off the arrow key. If we are forced to do that on keydown or keyup, then it will only triger the event ONCE, and we'd have to keep stroking the keydown arrow to scroll to a newly marked element in a list, instead of just holding down the arrow key.

Comment: @MrCroft - or also listen to `onkeyup` and stop the event there.  Realistically you shouldn't be modifying UI behavior with Javascript, however.

Comment: @MarkKahn yeah, it's just that you have to listen to 2 events to be able to accomplish functionality that should have been accessible through 1 event alone, in my opinion. It is possible though, yeah... Nothing's really impossible, there are always ways to do it. I just think it should have been accessible altogether through the keypress event alone. Unfortunately, it's not.

Comment: useful tool for confirming keycodes: https://blog.pothoven.net/2008/05/keydown-vs-keypress-in-javascript.html

Comment: keyup is most of the time what you want

Comment: If you care about quick response then key up is "slow" for example if you made a game, you wouldn't want to act upon when the key is let go, you want to act as soon as the key registers, so you would want to do it on key down, but make sure not to repeat the key being held down until the key triggers it's associated key up and then you can reset it ready for another key down.

Comment: Can you write a code example?

Comment: Please do not use this solution anymore!! It is old and many browsers do not support it anymore!!! Instead, consider using the "event.key" instead.

Answer (score 297):

On key up and down call function. There are different codes for each key.

```
document.onkeydown = checkKey;

function checkKey(e) {

    e = e || window.event;

    if (e.keyCode == '38') {
        // up arrow
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
        // down arrow
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
       // left arrow
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
       // right arrow
    }

}
```

Comment: What does the second line do?

Comment: 'e = e || window.event;'

Comment: It will get the event

Comment: To clarify, 'e || window.event' means that if 'e' is a defined value, it will be the result of the '||' expression. If 'e' is not defined, 'window.event' will be the result of the '||' expression. So it's basically shorthand for:

`e = e ? e : window.event;`

Or:
`if (typeof(e) === "undefined") { e = window.event; } `

Comment: It's to make it work on old versions of IE (pre IE9) where the event was not passed into the handler function.

Comment: Just to note keyCode is a number and === should ideally be used

Comment: @alexrogins have you checked? http://jsfiddle.net/AjKjU/86/ and http://jsfiddle.net/AjKjU/87/.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your what your fiddle is showing. Have I checked what? I have edited your answer, please can you approve it as it is correct? Should be http://jsfiddle.net/AjKjU/88/

Comment: @ketan the point was that keyCode is a number and should be checked like `keyCode === 32`, not `keyCode == '32'` or `keyCode === '32'`.

Comment: keyCode is deprecated. Please see 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

Use key instead ie e.key === 'ArrowDown'

Comment: Better than accepted answer because it actually gives code example.

Comment: isnt e.keyCode deprecated and e.which as well ? is there any alternative to finding the ASCII code ?@ketan

Comment: As @SyedKhizaruddin pointed out, e.keyCode is deprecated. The answer should be updated.

Answer (score 290):

## event.key === "ArrowRight"...

More recent and much cleaner: use `event.key`. No more arbitrary number codes! If you are transpiling or know your users are all on modern browsers, use this!

```
node.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    const key = event.key; // "ArrowRight", "ArrowLeft", "ArrowUp", or "ArrowDown"
});
```

**Verbose Handling:**

```
switch (event.key) {
    case "ArrowLeft":
        // Left pressed
        break;
    case "ArrowRight":
        // Right pressed
        break;
    case "ArrowUp":
        // Up pressed
        break;
    case "ArrowDown":
        // Down pressed
        break;
}
```

**Modern Switch Handling:**

```
const callback = {
    "ArrowLeft"  : leftHandler,
    "ArrowRight" : rightHandler,
    "ArrowUp"    : upHandler,
    "ArrowDown"  : downHandler,
}[event.key]
callback?.()
```

> NOTE: The old properties (`.keyCode` and `.which`) are Deprecated.

## `"w", "a", "s", "d"` for direction, use `event.code`

To support users who are using non-qwerty/English keyboard layouts, you should instead use `event.code`. This will preserve physical key location, even if resulting character changes.

`event.key` would be <kbd>,</kbd> on Dvorak and <kbd>z</kbd> on Azerty, making your game unplayable.

```
const {code} = event
if (code === "KeyW") // KeyA, KeyS, KeyD
```

Optimally, you also allow key remapping, which benefits the player regardless of their situation.

P.S. `event.code` is the same ***for arrows***

[`key` Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

[`code` Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code)

[Supported Browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-key)

Comment: Thank you for using `key` and not `keyCode`, that was deprecated.

Comment: Note from MDN: Internet Explorer, Edge (16 and earlier), and Firefox (36 and earlier) use "Left", "Right", "Up", and "Down" instead of "ArrowLeft", "ArrowRight", "ArrowUp", and "ArrowDown".

Comment: as event.keyCode is deprecated this should be the accepted answer

Comment: I just loved the modern switch handling

Comment: I presume that `event.key === "ArrowRight"` is not doing a string comparison to check a single keypress.  Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 102):

Possibly the tersest formulation:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            alert('left');
            break;
        case 38:
            alert('up');
            break;
        case 39:
            alert('right');
            break;
        case 40:
            alert('down');
            break;
    }
};
```

Demo (thanks to user Angus Grant): http://jsfiddle.net/angusgrant/E3tE6/

This should work cross-browser.  Leave a comment if there is a browser where it does not work.

There are other ways to get the key code (e.which, e.charCode, and window.event instead of e), but they should not be necessary.  You can try most of them out at http://www.asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html. 
Note that event.keycode does not work with onkeypress in Firefox, but it does work with onkeydown.

Comment: I had to look up the definition of [*terse*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/terse), then I (sprightfully) postulated that *tersest* was an improper conjugation; alas, I concede: my solicitude was [refutable](https://books.google.ca/books?id=SnshAQAAMAAJ&q=%22tersest%22).

Answer (score 22):

Use `keydown`, not `keypress` for non-printable keys such as arrow keys:

```
function checkKey(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    alert(e.keyCode);
}

document.onkeydown = checkKey;
```

The best JavaScript key event reference I've found (beating the pants off quirksmode, for example) is here: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Comment: Now `keypress` has been marked as deprecated

Answer (score 20):

Modern answer since **[keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) is now deprecated** in favor of **[key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)**:

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    switch (e.key) {
        case 'ArrowUp':
            // up arrow
            break;
        case 'ArrowDown':
            // down arrow
            break;
        case 'ArrowLeft':
            // left arrow
            break;
        case 'ArrowRight':
            // right arrow
    }
};
```

Answer (score 18):

I believe the most recent method would be:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const key = event.key; // "ArrowRight", "ArrowLeft", "ArrowUp", or "ArrowDown"
  switch (key) { // change to event.key to key to use the above variable
    case "ArrowLeft":
      // Left pressed
      <do something>
      break;
    case "ArrowRight":
      // Right pressed
      <do something>
      break;
    case "ArrowUp":
      // Up pressed
      <do something>
      break;
    case "ArrowDown":
      // Down pressed
      <do something>
      break;
  }
});
```

This assumes the developer wants the code to be active anywhere on the page and the client should ignore any other key presses.  Eliminate the event.preventDefault(); line if keypresses, including those caught by this handler should still be active.

Answer (score 9):

```
function checkArrowKeys(e){
    var arrs= ['left', 'up', 'right', 'down'], 
    key= window.event? event.keyCode: e.keyCode;
    if(key && key>36 && key<41) alert(arrs[key-37]);
}
document.onkeydown= checkArrowKeys;
```

Comment: Doesn't it worth to put `arrs` outside of the function? No need to recreate it every call

Answer (score 9):

Here's an example implementation:

```
var targetElement = $0 || document.body;

function getArrowKeyDirection (keyCode) {
  return {
    37: 'left',
    39: 'right',
    38: 'up',
    40: 'down'
  }[keyCode];
}

function isArrowKey (keyCode) {
  return !!getArrowKeyDirection(keyCode);
}

targetElement.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
  var direction,
      keyCode = event.keyCode;

  if (isArrowKey(keyCode)) {
    direction = getArrowKeyDirection(keyCode);

    console.log(direction);
  }
});
```

Comment: I am getting **$0 is not defined** `var targetElement = typeof $0 !== 'undefined' ? $0 : document.body;` or just: `var targetElement = document.body;` is ok

Answer (score 8):

Here's how I did it:

```
var leftKey = 37, upKey = 38, rightKey = 39, downKey = 40;
var keystate;
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    keystate[e.keyCode] = true;
});
document.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    delete keystate[e.keyCode];
});

if (keystate[leftKey]) {
//code to be executed when left arrow key is pushed.
}
if (keystate[upKey]) {
//code to be executed when up arrow key is pushed.
}
if (keystate[rightKey]) {
//code to be executed when right arrow key is pushed.
}
if (keystate[downKey]) {
//code to be executed when down arrow key is pushed.
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Arrow Keys are triggered on **keyup**

```
$(document).on("keyup", "body", function(e) {
 if (e.keyCode == 38) {
    // up arrow
    console.log("up arrow")
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 40) {
      // down arrow
      console.log("down arrow")
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    // left arrow
    console.log("lefy arrow")
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    // right arrow
    console.log("right arrow")
  }
})
```

*onkeydown allows ctrl, alt, shits*

*onkeyup allows tab, up arrows, down arrows, left arrows, down arrows*

Answer (score 4):

I've been able to trap them with jQuery:

```
$(document).keypress(function (eventObject) {
    alert(eventObject.keyCode);
});
```

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/AjKjU/

Comment: `keypress` won't work with arrow keys. You have to use `$(document).on('keydown', function() {...})` instead

Answer (score 4):

That is the working code for chrome and firefox

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function leftArrowPressed() {
      alert("leftArrowPressed" );
      window.location = prevUrl  
    }

    function rightArrowPressed() {
      alert("rightArrowPressed" );
      window.location = nextUrl  
    }
    function topArrowPressed() {
      alert("topArrowPressed" );
      window.location = prevUrl  
    }

    function downArrowPressed() {
      alert("downArrowPressed" );
      window.location = nextUrl  
    }

        document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
                        var nextPage = $("#next_page_link")
                        var prevPage = $("#previous_page_link")
                        nextUrl = nextPage.attr("href")
                        prevUrl = prevPage.attr("href")
        evt = evt || window.event;
        switch (evt.keyCode) {
                case 37:
                leftArrowPressed(nextUrl);
                break;

                case 38:
                topArrowPressed(nextUrl);
                break;

                 case 39:
                rightArrowPressed(prevUrl);
                break;

                case 40:
                downArrowPressed(prevUrl);
                break;

        }
    };


</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>
<a id="previous_page_link" href="http://www.latest-tutorial.com">Latest Tutorials</a> 
<a id="next_page_link" href="http://www.zeeshanakhter.com">Zeeshan Akhter</a>
 </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I was also looking for this answer until I came across this post.

I've found another solution to know the keycode of the different keys, courtesy to my problem.  I just wanted to share my solution.

Just use keyup/keydown event to write the value in the console/alert the same using `event.keyCode`. like-

```
console.log(event.keyCode) 

// or

alert(event.keyCode)
```

- rupam

Answer (score 3):

That's shorter.

`function IsArrows (e) {
   return (e.keyCode >= 37 && e.keyCode <= 40); 
}`

Comment: short is good: `if ([37,38,39,40].indexOf(e.keyCode)!=-1){
                console.log('arrow pressed')
                }`

Answer (score 3):

This library rocks!
https://craig.is/killing/mice

```
Mousetrap.bind('up up down down left right left right b a enter', function() {
    highlight([21, 22, 23]);
});
```

You need to press the sequence a bit fast to highlight the code in that page though.

Answer (score 3):

With [key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) and ES6.

This gives you a separate function for each arrow key without using switch and also works with the 2,4,6,8 keys in the numpad when `NumLock` is on.

```js
const element = document.querySelector("textarea"),
  ArrowRight = k => {
    console.log(k);
  },
  ArrowLeft = k => {
    console.log(k);
  },
  ArrowUp = k => {
    console.log(k);
  },
  ArrowDown = k => {
    console.log(k);
  },
  handler = {
    ArrowRight,
    ArrowLeft,
    ArrowUp,
    ArrowDown
  };

element.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
  const k = e.key;

  if (handler.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
    handler[k](k);
  }
});
```

```html
<p>Click the textarea then try the arrows</p>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

Re answers that you need `keydown` not `keypress`.

Assuming you want to move something continuously while the key is pressed, I find that `keydown` works for all browsers except Opera. For Opera, `keydown` only triggers on 1st press. To accommodate Opera use:

```
document.onkeydown = checkKey;
document.onkeypress = checkKey;
function checkKey(e)
{ etc etc
```

Answer (score 2):

In the off chance you're still developing with desktops in mind in 2023:

KeyboardEvent: keyCode property *has been deprecated*

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

Use the ket property
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key](https://%20%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code)

```js
// run snippet and click a key to see which key you clicked:

document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => { 
 alert(`You clicked ${event.key}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use jquery then you can also do like this,

```
 $(document).on("keydown", '.class_name', function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 37) {
        console.log('left arrow pressed');
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 38) {
        console.log('up arrow pressed');
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 39) {
        console.log('right arrow pressed');
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 40) {
        console.log('down arrow pressed');
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

control the Key codes `%=37` and `&=38`... and only arrow keys left=37  up=38

```
function IsArrows (e) {
   return ( !evt.shiftKey && (e.keyCode >= 37 && e.keyCode <= 40)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect arrow keypresses but not need specific in Javascript

```
function checkKey(e) {
   if (e.keyCode !== 38 || e.keyCode !== 40 || e.keyCode !== 37 || e.keyCode !== 39){
    // do something
   };
}
```