# highlights P tag with next and prev

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to allow the use to slide up and down when pressing up arrow and down arrow, I mean if "roma" is highlighted and I pressed down then "milan" should be highlighted. Here is my HTML:

```
<li id="place">
  <p>roma</p>
  <p>milan</p>
  <p>napoli</p>
</li>
```

I want to do this using Javascript, perhaps using `onclick()`.
which javascript attribute should i used and how to hightlight something using css
thank you

Comment: Your "hop for an answer" seems like request for a working piece of code. That's not what SO was made for.

Comment: for sure not the answer , but i want to know which javascript attribut should be used and how can i hightlight something using css

Comment: i will edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append a CSS class to highlight the respective element upon clicking it. Using jQuery toggle will allow you to toggle the highlighting of an element. jsFiddle example coming soon...

**jQuery Example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/2NS5V/2/

**JavaScript Example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/GDEeW/1/

Comment: Remember he said **javascript**, *not* **jquery** :)

Comment: yeah :) I'm creating an example for both.

Comment: i really thank you , but i don't know jQuery 
in css how can i hightlight something ?

Comment: you can highlight simply by changing the CSS background-color

Comment: good , and how can i make the highlight remove from p tag to another p tag , like my exapmple from roma to milan , should i used javascipt ?

Comment: Yeah, you should use JavaScript.

Comment: what is the method to call it to listen for pressing up arrow and down arrow ? thank you

Comment: really thank you man for the example , i really thank you , hope u a good life :)

Comment: i saw the first example , and i will see javascript one , i really thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaank you

Comment: the last thing , how can i tell java script to do that when the using click the up and down arrow , not a prev and next button ?

Comment: Up and Down keyboard arrows? Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597060/detecting-arrow-keys-in-javascript

Comment: i understood ur javascript code , but if i want to use it in a function have i to call that function when displaying the page , ? something like onload ?

Comment: Whilst I can't dispute that your code works, this is a god awful solution to the problem. You have hard-coded the number of options in the list, and what is worse, you have hard-coded how to highlight each  of the possible options, what would happen if this was a list of over 10,000 options? Would you really write a switch case fro each of the possible options?