# Do something on left/right arrow press

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I want to trigger a click event on another element, when a left or right arrow is pressed. Here is the code:

```
$(window).keypress(function (e) {
  var key = e.which;
  if(key == 13 || key == 39) { // the enter key code or right arrow
    $('.next').click();
    return false;  
  } else if(key == 37) { // left arrow
    $('.prev').click();
    return false;  
  }
});
```

With <kbd>Enter</kbd> key it works like a charm, however on arrow press, nothing happens, like a Magikarp that uses splash! :) What am I missing?

Relevant question: [Press left and right arrow to change image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26443828/press-left-and-right-arrow-to-change-image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arrow keys don't trigger a `keypress` event, but they *do* trigger a `keyup` or `keydown` event.

Best to use `keyup`, because `keydown` can be triggered multiple times while you're holding down a key.

```
$(window).keyup(function (e) {
  var key = e.which;
  if(key == 13 || key == 39) { // the enter key code or right arrow
    $('.next').click();
    return false;  
  } else if(key == 37) { // left arrow
    $('.prev').click();
    return false;  
  }
});
```

Comment: Once again Rick, thank you! Your edit was the answer to the question I was about to ask!

Comment: keyCode is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent). It's better to use `key` or  `code` above IE9+ .