# Moving image left and right with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

OK, here is the updated, and working code. Making the image relative did the trick. Now the only thing left is as soon as I remove my finger from the key, I want the image to stop moving. How would I properly use the keyup?

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
        <img id="pic" src="run0.png" alt="image" height="100" width="100" style="position: relative;"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script> 

$(document).keydown(function(event){
     var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);                
                if(keycode == '39'){
                    $("#pic").animate({
                         left: '+=10px',
                    });
                }
     });

</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would also prefer no to have to put an image on the document first with HTML, but to just append it to the document from Javascript/jQuery. And if anyone can help me do it with pure Javascript that would be appreciated.

Comment: You have syntax errors in there: `(index):27 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: After the `var keycode = ...` line you have a random ending curly brace.

Answer (score 2):

Arrow keys can't be detected with keypress. Read : [Detecting arrow key presses in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597060/detecting-arrow-key-presses-in-javascript)

Also for the left property to affect the image.. it should be absolutely placed in page.
Here is a sample demo : https://jsfiddle.net/6haxsbz9/

HTML:

```
<img id="pic" src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="image" width="100" />
```

CSS:

```
img {
    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
    top:10px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function () {

    $(document).keydown(function (event) {
        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if (keycode == '39') {
            $("#pic").animate({
                left: '+=5px',
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: You were faster... I'll delete my answer

Comment: making the position relative did the trick. From reading the stuff from the link, it seems keypress only works with some browsers while keyup/down is more universal. (See my edit) just need the animation to stop on keyup.

Answer (score 0):

First, as said in the comments, fix syntax errors!

Then you want to animate your pic with  the CSS property `left` which is part of CSS `position`. If you add that to your image it should work (I just took keycode `97` for `a` because I don't know what `39` is):

**HTML:**

```
<img id="pic" src="run0.png" alt="image" height="100" width="100" />
```

**CSS:**

```
#pic {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).keypress(function (event) {
    // var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);

    console.log(event.keyCode);
    if (event.keyCode == '97') {
        $("#pic").animate({
            left: '+=5px',
        });
    }
});
```

See jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/914m6ut3/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a relative position to your image:

```
<img id="pic" src="run0.png" alt="image" height="100" width="100" style="position: relative;"  />
```

Comment: That made it work, thanks! :) I'll come back and give you a point when my rep is at 15!