# Keypress not responding to character codes

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 32) {
        alert('You pressed spacebar!');
    }
});

$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        alert('You pressed enter!');
    }
});

$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 40) {
        alert('You pressed down arrow!');
    }
});
```

Here's my javascript file. There is no CSS and the HTML is just a blank skeleton.

It reads the enter and spacebar just fine, but the down arrow, up arrow, or pretty much any key I press that isn't enter or spacebar does not register?

How would one solve this problem?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If this could help :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402698/binding-arrow-keys-in-js-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrow keys don't generate a `keypress` event. They generate `keydown` and `keyup` events.

Note that while letters keys do generate `keypress`, the `which` value may not be the value you expect. On my browser and operating system, for instance, pressing the <kbd>a</kbd> key generates `which = 65`, which is the character code for `A`, not `a`. Key codes are *key* codes, not *character* codes. More on [this no-longer-maintained, but still quite useful, page](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html).

**Live Example:** *(I added a `return false` to prevent default handling, since otherwise the Stack Snippet window tends to scroll around, but that isn't necessary to receive the event)*

```js
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 32) {
        display('You pressed spacebar!');
        return false;
    }
});

$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        display('You pressed enter!');
        return false;
    }
});

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 40) {
        display('You pressed down arrow!');
        return false;
    }
});

function display(msg) {
  $("<p>").text(msg).appendTo(document.body);
}
```

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Click this pane to focus it, then press spacebar, Enter, or down-arrow</p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Would that also be the case for letter keys?

Comment: @R.Little: No, letter keys generate `keypress`. Note, though, the `which` value may not be the value you're expecting for the character. Remember keycodes are *key* codes, not character codes. More on [this no-longer-maintained, but still quite useful, page](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597060/detecting-arrow-key-presses-in-javascript

Comment: Rather embarrassing the answer was this simple. I'll give you the green checkmark thingy when it lets me... in about 7 minutes