# JavaScript Key Press

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible,  using JavaScript or jQuery, to perform an action when a user presses a certain key on the keyboard?

For example: User presses down the "A" key and a div changes from hidden to visible

Thanks

Comment: yes obvious, but what have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. Currently the answer to your question is "Yes it is possible"

Comment: See [Detecting arrow key presses in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597060/detecting-arrow-key-presses-in-javascript) for examples.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is

See the following:

[KeyDown Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp)

[KeyPress Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp)

[KeyUp Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp)

jQuery has wrappers for all these events

Comment: This is not an answer

Comment: Funny-it's the answer you gave, and even called it an answer "Yes it's possible"

Comment: That was not an invitation. I also closed as duplicate instead of posting as actual answer. The question was not worth an answer at all.

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is a jQuery plugin for just this kind of thing, and also google results are filled with answers.

http://plugins.jquery.com/hotkeys/