# ReactJS keyevent not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Eventually I'm trying to move the object on the screen using keyboard arrow keys. At the moment I'm trying to see if the code responds to keys. It does not. I press arrow up and nothing gets output to browser console.

```
_handleKey(event){
    console.log(event);
    if(event.keyCode == 38){
      console.log("Arrow Up");
    }
   }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener("keyPress", this._handleKey, false);
  }
```

The full code is here:
http://codepen.io/wasteland/pen/GZvWeo

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting arrow key presses in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597060/detecting-arrow-key-presses-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to use is the `keydown` event.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", this._handleKey, false);
```

[*arrow keys are only triggered by onkeydown, not onkeypress*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597060/detecting-arrow-key-presses-in-javascript)

Take a look into this as well

http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/KeyPress-KeyDown-KeyUp-The-Difference-Between-Javascript-Key-Events.aspx