# How to add keyboard functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a flip book. How to add keyboard functions for turning pages??

Source code- https://github.com/Ananthavijay/News-Book

Preview- http://hardcore-morse-14df89.bitballoon.com/

Comment: Please review [ask] for tips on how to ask a well-formed question-- this will invite useful answers.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In Jquery, you can bind a keypress event to particular function like

```
$( "#target" ).keypress(function() {
console.log( "Handler for .keypress() called." );
});
```

if you want to bind the event to only a specific key for example left and right arrow keys;

```
$( "#target" ).keypress(function(event) {
  if(event.which === 37 ){ //for left arrow key
     console.log( "Handler for .keypress() called." );
   }
});
```

Check out more key codes [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/)

Answer (score 0):

How to use keys "left", "right", "top", "bottom":

[Detecting arrow key presses in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597060/detecting-arrow-key-presses-in-javascript)

You can use it with `document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){ 
// your code 
})`