# Making buttons accessible

Tags: javascript, html

I am having trouble making my buttons accessible highlight when tabbed, It is not working I have looked on MDN and W3 schools 
I have tried ARIA: button role on MDN and its not working.

Hello I am sorry, I am making a calculator. the buttons on the calculator need to be accessible to the visually impaired. I am trying to make the Clear button or first button be highlighted and the rest of the buttons be able to be accessed by the tab key

This is the html for the buttons. Should I use span instead?

```html
<div id="keyboard">
  <button class="operator addMore" title="Clear" id="clear">C</button>
  <button class="operator" id="backspace">CE</button>
  <button class="operator" id="%">%</button>
  <button class="operator" id="/">&#247;</button>
  <button class="number" id="7">7</button>
  <button class="number" id="8">8</button>
  <button class="number" id="9">9</button>
  <button class="operator" id="*">&times;</button>
  <button class="number" id="4">4</button>
  <button class="number addMore" title="Number 5">5</button>
  <button class="number" id="6">6</button>
  <button class="operator" id="-">-</button>
  <button class="number" id="1">1</button>
  <button class="number" id="2">2</button>
  <button class="number" id="3">3</button>
  <button class="operator" id="+">+</button>
  <button class="empty" id="empty"></button>
  <button class="number" id="0">0</button>
  <button class="number" id="decimal">.</button>
  <button class="operator" id="=">=</button>
</div>
So far I got this this from my research.

<script>
document.onkeydown = checkKey;

function checkKey(e) {

    e = e || window.event;

    if (e.keyCode == '38') {
        // up arrow
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
        // down arrow
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
       // left arrow
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
       // right arrow
    }

</script>
```

I am having trouble making my buttons accessible highlight when tabbed, It is not working I have looked on MDN and W3 schools I have tried ARIA: button role on MDN and its not working.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "making my buttons accessible highlight when tabbed?"

Comment: The buttons 'highlight' for me using the default browser caret/focus when I use the tab key after using the `Run code snippet` button above, so more detail is needed.

Comment: why do you have id values like this -> id="%" , id="*" ? never seen that before

Comment: Hello I am sorry, I am making a calculator. the buttons on the calculator need to be accessible to the visually impaired. I am trying to make the Clear button or first button be highlighted and the rest of the buttons be able to be accessed the arrow keys

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting arrow key presses in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597060/detecting-arrow-key-presses-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Add the insert the "button" tag into a "a href=""" tag

Comment: this only would add clutter to the DOM - and is not required for `<button>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and add all css class for all button.

```js
$('body').on('keydown', '#keyboard', function(e) {
  debugger;
  var focusName = $(document.activeElement).html();
  $(document.activeElement).addClass(focusName);
  if (e.which == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```css
.c {
  background-color: red;
}

.ce {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="keyboard">
  <button class="operator addMore" title="Clear" id="clear">C</button>
  <button class="operator" id="backspace">CE</button>
  <button class="operator" id="%">%</button>
  <button class="operator" id="/">&#247;</button>
  <button class="number" id="7">7</button>
  <button class="number" id="8">8</button>
  <button class="number" id="9">9</button>
  <button class="operator" id="*">&times;</button>
  <button class="number" id="4">4</button>
  <button class="number addMore" title="Number 5">5</button>
  <button class="number" id="6">6</button>
  <button class="operator" id="-">-</button>
  <button class="number" id="1">1</button>
  <button class="number" id="2">2</button>
  <button class="number" id="3">3</button>
  <button class="operator" id="+">+</button>
  <button class="empty" id="empty"></button>
  <button class="number" id="0">0</button>
  <button class="number" id="decimal">.</button>
  <button class="operator" id="=">=</button>
</div>
```

```
<style>
    .c
    {
        background-color:red;
    }
    .ce{
        background-color:green;
    }

</style>
<script>
    $('body').on('keydown', '#keyboard', function (e) {
        debugger;
        var focusName = $(document.activeElement).html();
        $(document.activeElement).addClass(focusName);
        if (e.which == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: do you mean make a new class for each button and add the class?

Comment: any logic you can use. if you want to only highlight tabbed button so you have to remove other button class and add highlighted button class.