# Javascript Event Handler in Python web page not working

Tags: javascript, python, event-handling

I have a web page generated by Python which needs to have a Javascript event handler enabled.  The code below returns an error: node is not defined.

The following question has an answer which looks very promising, but I am missing the "node" variable assignment.  I would add a comment, but the system won't let me do so.  It says I need a reputation of 50 to add a comment.

[Detecting arrow key presses in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597060/detecting-arrow-key-presses-in-javascript)

```
<BODY>
<script type="text/javascript">
node.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    const key = event.key; // "ArrowRight", "ArrowLeft", "ArrowUp", or "ArrowDown"
});
switch (event.key) {
    case "ArrowLeft":
        // Left pressed
        alert( "Left Arrow" );
        break;
    case "ArrowRight":
        // Right pressed
        alert( "Right Arrow" );
        break;
    case "ArrowUp":
        // Up pressed
        alert( "Up Arrow" );
        break;
    case "ArrowDown":
        // Down pressed
        alert( "Down Arrow" );
        break;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to listen for keydown events on your entire page you can replace `node` with `document` which is already defined within JS. You'll also need to move your switch statement inside the event listener's callback function like so:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // prevent page from scrolling
  const key = event.key; // "ArrowRight", "ArrowLeft", "ArrowUp", or "ArrowDown"
  switch (key) { // change to event.key to key to use the above variable
    case "ArrowLeft":
      // Left pressed
      alert("Left Arrow");
      break;
    case "ArrowRight":
      // Right pressed
      alert("Right Arrow");
      break;
    case "ArrowUp":
      // Up pressed
      alert("Up Arrow");
      break;
    case "ArrowDown":
      // Down pressed
      alert("Down Arrow");
      break;
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<p>Some text</p>
```

*Explanation:*

Essentially `document` represents your entire page. You can add an event listener to your document (ie page) such that a function will execute when something happens. In our code, we're adding a `keydown` event listener which means we want to execute some code when a key is pressed down. The code which will run is the code in the `function(event) {...}`. When an event occurs, we can get specific details about that event from the `event` argument passed into the triggered function. We can get many details from the `event` object passed into our function, and one of those is the `key` which was pressed. In our code we get the key pressed using `evet.key` and then store it in a variable called `key`. We then use a `switch` statement to check which key was pressed, and execute the relevent code if a specific key appears.

Comment: Thank you!  That works.  I don't understand exactly why, but I will study it to get my head around it.

Comment: I think I do understand this, now, but I do have one remaining question:  How do I disable the arrow keys for the scroll functions?  I want to dedicate the action of the arrow keys to this function, regardless of whether the page extends beyond the edge of the screen.

Comment: You can add `event.preventDefault();` (see example code snippet) to stop the page from scrolling.