# How to console.log when I press a key in the keyboard?

Tags: javascript

I want my code to `console.log` when I press number pad 1
I tried this, but is not working:

```js
function presskey1(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 97){
        console.log(Element)
    }
}
presskey1();
```

97 = numpad 1 codeKey

Comment: There's a number of missing parts here. Can you provide a working example?

Comment: thats why im asking , im not sure how this even works

Comment: In the example you're not passing `e` to the function; you're passing empty arguments, which turn `e` into `undefined`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting arrow key presses in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597060/detecting-arrow-key-presses-in-javascript)

Comment: No, so I want it to **console.log** when I press number 1 on the keyboard.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how you can do it! You should use event listener for keydown event and also key code for numpad 1 is `Numpad1`

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', keyPressed);

function keyPressed(e) {
  if(e.code == "Numpad1") {
    console.log("Numpad1 Pressed");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  if (event.key === "1"){
     console.log(event.target) 
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

// this works for me.
// it logs relevant keycode info.

```
  const keyCodes = () => {
  document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    console.log(
      'keyCodeDEP', e.which,
      'key', e.key,
      'code', e.code,
      'location', e.location
    );
  });
};
keyCodes();
```

https://keycode.info/