# arrowkey eventlistener not working for my website

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

My image gallery website displays a thumbnail at the top, and when each image in the thumbnail is clicked on, it becomes the big display image in the background of the website, I would like to make it so when the left and right arrow keys are pressed, it also changes the display image depending on which arrow key has been pressed. This is my html and javascript, I have made some changes and decided to use the event.key inside a function. However I am unsure on how I would write the selectNextImage function, which when the arrow keys are pressed, is meant to swap the display image to the next one in the array.

```js
//declare global variables
let thumbNailBox = document.getElementById(`thumbnail-box`)
//set displayImage directly to img tag
let displayImage = document.getElementById(`display`)
//set announcer
const announcer = document.getElementById(`announcer`)
//make images object array
   

 let images = [
        {
            url: `https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a4c6a31d-c586-4ac6-9172-1d5c2b9d41cf/d60wfgx-49772b1b-8b09-4a01-84eb-f04d8dd81f43.png/v1/fill/w_999,h_800,q_70,strp/south_park__wallpaper_eric_cartman_by_hieifireblaze_d60wfgx-pre.jpg?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9ODIwIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYTRjNmEzMWQtYzU4Ni00YWM2LTkxNzItMWQ1YzJiOWQ0MWNmXC9kNjB3Zmd4LTQ5NzcyYjFiLThiMDktNGEwMS04NGViLWYwNGQ4ZGQ4MWY0My5wbmciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9MTAyNCJ9XV0sImF1ZCI6WyJ1cm46c2VydmljZTppbWFnZS5vcGVyYXRpb25zIl19.oX3t6Ps7YpCVd7OZDtwYyaIqTYocSNSLYGp6dJaIPKY` ,

            alt: `cartman with a red background` 
        },
        {
            url: `https://wallpapers.com/images/hd/south-park-s-stan-marsh-simple-art-ad3wjf4su96o4mam.jpg`,
            alt: `Stan with a blue background`
        }, 
        {
            url: `https://facts.net/wp-content/uploads/2023/09/22-facts-about-kyle-broflovski-south-park-1694601417.jpg` ,
            alt: `Kyle with a green background`
        },
        {
            url:`https://www.thefactsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/kenny-facts.jpg`, 
            alt: `Kenny with an oramge background`
        }
    ]

//create thumbnails
const makeThumbNails = (images) => 
{
    //loop through array of images
    images.forEach( (image) => 
    {
    //create image tag using javascript , save to variable
    let img = document.createElement(`img`)
    //link src and alt
    img.src = image.url
    img.alt = image.alt
    //create class for img tag
    img.className= `img`
    // event listener
    img.addEventListener("click",() =>
    {
        console.log(`image.alt`)
        //call createDisplayImage
        createDisplayImage(image)
      
    })
    //add arrow keys event listener to full website
    function handleArrowKeyPress(event)
    {
        if (event.key === 'ArrowRight')
        {
            selectNextImage(1);
        }
        else if (event.key === 'ArrowLeft')
        {
            selectNextImage(-1)
        }
    }
    //append to thumbNailBox
    thumbNailBox.appendChild(img)
    //announce alt text 
    announceAltText(images.alt)
    //
    })
}       

//get display image, seperate from thumbnail bar
function createDisplayImage(images)
{
    //set src and alt dire
    displayImage.src = images.url
    displayImage.alt = images.alt
    displayImage.className = `display-img`
    announceAltText(displayImage.alt)
}

//announce alt text function
function announceAltText(altText)
{
    announcer.textContent = `New image displayed: ${altText}`
}

// call makeThumbnails to images object array
makeThumbNails(images)
//set display image on loading the page 
createDisplayImage(images[0])
```

```html
    <div id="thumbnail-box" class="thumbnail-box" tabindex="0">

    </div>
    <section tabindex="0">
      <!-- directly to tag method -->
      <img src="" alt="" id="display" tabindex="0">
    </section>
    <div id="announcer" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true"></div>
```

Comment: Refer to this decade old SO post. Nothing's changed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597060/detecting-arrow-key-presses-in-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting arrow key presses in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597060/detecting-arrow-key-presses-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

The `event` object doesn't have properties named `arrowRight` and `arrowLeft`, thus your checks always return `undefined` which when used as a Boolean is considered to be `false`, so that your code inside the `if` is never executed.

Use `event.key` instead.

```js
window.addEventListener(`keydown`, (event) => {
    if (event.key === "ArrowRight" || event.key === "ArrowLeft") {
        moveBy(displayImage)
    }
})
```

Also, as your current code stands, you're checking twice for Arrow Right, both times running the same code when true. Is that intentional?