# Bind enter key to specific button on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<input type="button" id="save_post" class="button" value="Post" style="cursor:pointer;"/>
```

How can I bind the enter key on the persons keyboard to this specific button on the page? It's not in a form, and nor do I want it to be.

Thanks!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402698/binding-arrow-keys-in-js-jquery

Comment: Significant flaw with all methods presented to date: Textboxes will also submit on enter, instead of allowing for new lines.

Comment: @Kaji Shift+Enter should still work but I agree it's a problem

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This will click the button regardless of where the "Enter" happens on the page:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
    if (e.which == 13){
        $("#save_post").click();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 23):

If you want to use pure javascript :

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  switch (e.which || e.keyCode) {
        case 13 : //Your Code Here (13 is ascii code for 'ENTER')
            break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Pure JavaScript option is always a bonus

Comment: window.onkeydown or document.onkeydown? guess it doesn't matter in this case

Comment: that's a global function, it won't be that smart to override it.

Answer (score 12):

using jQuery :

```
$('body').on('keypress', 'input', function(args) {
    if (args.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#save_post").click();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Or to bind specific inputs to different buttons you can use selectors

```
$('body').on('keypress', '#MyInputId', function(args) {
    if (args.keyCode == 13) {
        $('#MyButtonId').click();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Why do we need to `return false`? The form will not submit.

Comment: Hi @Mai, in the question it specifically asks "It's not in a form, and nor do I want it to be"!

Answer (score 3):

Vanilla JS version with listener:

```
window.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    alert('enter was pressed!');
  }
});
```

Also don't forget to remove event [listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener), if this code is shared between the pages.

Comment: event.keyCode seems to be deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not quite what you're looking for but there is a HTML property that lets you assign a specific button called an access key to focus or trigger an element. It's like this:

```
<a href='https://www.google.com' accesskey='h'>
```

This can be done with most elements.

Here's the catch: it doesn't always work. for IE and chrome, you need to be holding alt as well. On firefox, you need to be holding alt and shift (and control if on mac). For safari, you need to be holding control and alt. On opera 15+ you need alt, before 12.1 you need shift and esc.

Source: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_accesskey.asp)