# html input type button submit on enter

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

Does anyone know how to make submit button on enter in my case?

```
<div data-bind="with: idea">
    <input type="text" data-bind='value:itemToAdd, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' />
    <input type="button" id="addButton" data-bind="click:$parent.addItem, enable: itemToAdd" value="add" />
    <ul data-bind="foreach:allItems">
        <li> <span data-bind="text:$data"></span>
                <input type="button" data-bind="click:$root.removeItem.bind($parent, $data)" value="-" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[Here's fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mk_yo/M2xDF/42/)

Comment: Did you try input type="submit"

Comment: 'make submit button' - what do you mean ? Without a `form` how can  you submit on pressing the Enter key?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, that's why I'm asking here

Comment: You should try ajax with bind enter to button: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542413/bind-enter-key-to-specific-button-on-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to implement it this way:

```
<form data-bind="with: idea, submit: addItem">
    <input type="text" data-bind='value:itemToAdd, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' />
    <input type="submit" id="addButton" data-bind="enable: itemToAdd" value="add" />
    <ul data-bind="foreach:allItems">
        <li> <span data-bind="text:$data"></span>
                <input type="button" data-bind="click:$root.removeItem.bind($parent, $data)" value="-" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The idea is following: you're wrapping your controls with the `form` and adding `submit` binding to it, that means action, that will be performed on form submit. And now on pressing Enter inside the form you are actually submitting the from, that's why `submit` action will be performed.