# Arrow Keys reading as '0' in keypress event handler

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, keypress

Debugging with Firebug in Firefox 8.0.1, I attach a `keypress` event handler to an editable div. Every key press shows correctly in the console except the arrow keys, for which `e.which` in the console is showing up as 0.

How can I get the keycodes for the up and down arrow keys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you can't use `keypress` for the arrow keys, only `keyup` and `keydown`:

[Binding arrow keys in JS/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402698/binding-arrow-keys-in-js-jquery)

Comment: I believe the rationale is that the arrow keys don't produce a letter, or number, or symbol.