# Key Shortcuts on a web page

Tags: web-applications, key-events

Alright so for my website I'd like to enable keyboard shortcuts.
When left or right button is pressed on the keyboard, it opens an URL.
Also binding some other buttons too maybe.

Any clue how I can go about doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Binding arrow keys in JS/jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402698/binding-arrow-keys-in-js-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the javascript onkeydown event and getting the key code.

Or using a jQuery-plugin like [hotkeys](http://code.google.com/p/js-hotkeys/wiki/about) which offers key combinations like ctrl+c.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this page:

http://www.asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html