# capture keyboard down/up button clicks event from inside iframe and prevent page from moving up and down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

I have developed a simple [scrollbar plugin](https://github.com/vigneshvdm/cScroll/) which will detect down/up button click and move the content inside the div up/down.

So my question is can I prevent the up/down button click, from making the browser main scroll from moving up and down?!

In the image below, i want the scrollbar marked in blue(my plugin) to scroll down when I press down button. But the scroll in red box(Browser scroll) is scrolling !!

[image]

Comment: You need to surround your plugin with a `div` and an `overflow hidden` style to the div. That should get rid of your red scrollbar. Then you need to capture your down arrow key to make your plugin work. Look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402698/binding-arrow-keys-in-js-jquery)