# jQuery - Binding key presses to function

Tags: jquery, function, onkeypress

I know that this question has been asked and answered before, and I have found the answer already, but I had an issue for which I required some follow-up information, and as my rep is too low, I cannot comment on the relevant answer to ask for it!

I am using sygmoral's answer for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402698/binding-arrow-keys-in-js-jquery), which should be the second answer down the page. I am using two functions to operate an image slider, one to slide left, and one to slide right. When clicking the on-screen buttons with the mouse cursor, each function operates perfectly, but when using sygmoral's function for key presses, only one of the left/right arrow keys triggers the function properly...

The keypress function code goes like this:

```
    $(document).keydown(function(e){
        switch(e.which) {
            case 37:
            slideLeft();

            case 39:
            slideRight();

            default: return;                
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

case 39 works as it should. case 37 triggers the slideLeft() function, and the image slides left, but then immediately slides back to the right. If I swap cases 39 and 37, the opposite happens. Basically, only the second case will work properly.

Can anyone offer me a suggestion as to why this might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missing `break;` keyword in each branch of switch statement
so if you press left arrow you will get into case 37 - `slideLeft()` is processed and then rest of the code too (`slideRight();return;`)

see [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#Example%3a_Using_switch) documentation on MDN.

here is what you need:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    switch(e.which) {
        case 37:
            slideLeft();
            break;
        case 39:
            slideRight();
            break; // isn't needed in your case
        default:
            return;                
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks :) So simple! Is it obvious I've never used switch() before?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `break;` after calls to function, in each case...

For instance, instead of

```
case 37:
  slideLeft();
```

you should have

```
case 37:
  slideLeft();
  break;
```

For more info about switch statements in JavaScript, see http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Comment: Thanks man, good answer. You were just pipped to the post though!

Comment: Not quite, I posted at 10:46:26, as opposed to 10:50:37.

Comment: So you were! Sorry, I didn't realise you could see the exact time. I just assumed that the first answer down the list was the older one. My apologies.