# jQuery: How to detect arrow key press only on certain element

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, keydown, onkeydown

I am new to jQuery and am trying to find a way to **detect an arrow key press (only up and down)**. 
When searching for this online I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402698/binding-arrow-keys-in-js-jquery) from here.

This looks very good but I want to detect the arrow key press only **when the user is on an element with a certain class** (i.e. the element has focus) that is added dynamically to a page.

Specifically I would like to highlight the corresponding list item when pressing the up or down arrow key on a list with focus.

Is there a way this can be achieved and work cross-browser ?

It looks like this already happens automatically but in my case it doesn't work properly and always skips list items which is why I thought I can define it separately.

**Example element:**

```
<ul class="myClass" id="someID">
   <li><a href="#">Value1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Value2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Value3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Many thanks in advance for any help, 
Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
```

in your javascript code have

```
$(<selector>).keydown(function(e) {
```

where `<selector>` points to the element you want to track.

**UPDATE**

Better - since you mention dynamically added elements, use delegation structure of event binding:

```
$(document).on("keydown", ".<yourClassName>", function(e) {
```

Comment: Thanks, JNF but does this also cover dynamically added elements ?

Comment: @keewee279, see the last part of the answer

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for - thanks a lot ! Will accept as soon as I can. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard

```
$('body').keyup(function(e){...})
```

mechanizm and check the class of the current active element:

```
document.activeElement.classList
```