# Making a timer with code that can easily be reset

Tags: javascript, timer, key-bindings, stopwatch

I'm making a shot clock for my school's basketball team. A shot clock is a timer that counts down from 24 seconds. I have the skeleton for the timer right now, but I need to have particular key bindings. The key bindings should allow me to rest, pause, and play the timer.

```
var count=24;

var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000);

function timer()
{
  count=count-1;
  if (count <= 0)
  {
     clearInterval(counter);
     return;
  }

 document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=count + " secs";
}
```

Comment: http://jquerytimer.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you meant by "rest" the timer, I interpret this as "pause", so:

- <kbd>Space</kbd> = Pause / Play.
- <kbd>R</kbd> = Reset.

```js
var
  count=24,
  counter = setInterval(timer, 1000),
  running = true;

function timer() {
  count -= 1;
  
  if (count <= 0) {
    clearInterval(counter);
  }
  
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = count + " secs";
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  switch(e.keyCode) {
  
    case 32: // PLAY
      running ? clearInterval(counter) : counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);
      running = !running;
      break;
    
    case 82: // RESET
      clearInterval(counter);
      document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = 24 + " secs";
      count = 24;
      running = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="timer">24 secs</div>
```

Comment: I think by reset he means at any given time the timer will reset back to 24 seconds.

Comment: He wrote "rest" though, not reset. I've accommodated reset anyhow.

Comment: `e.keyCode` is deprecated. `e.key` or `e.code` should be used instead, which also makes the code easier to understand. Just keep in mind some old browsers used non-standard codes, so ,for example, left is usually `'LeftArrow'` and right is `'RightArrow'`, but on IE it's just `'Left'` and `'Right'` instead. Also, take a look at https://keyjs.dev. I will add information about these kinds of cross-browser incompatibilities soon! 

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to comment yet, but I recommend checking out this post [Binding arrow keys in JS/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402698/binding-arrow-keys-in-js-jquery)

The linked post explains how to bind arrow keys using js/jquery. Using http://keycode.info/ you can find out the keycodes of your desired keys and replace the current values then continue to build your code from there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code sample: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLvWJM

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $timer = $('#timer');
  var $timerStatus = $('#timerStatus');
  var timerValue = 24;
  var intervalId = null;
  var timerStatus = 'stopped';
  
  if(!$timer.length) {
    throw 'This timer is missing a <div> element.';
  }
  
  $(document).keydown(function(k) {
    if(k.which == 80) {
      if(timerStatus === 'playing') {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        timerStatus = 'stopped';
        updateTimerStatus();
        return;
      }
      
      intervalId = setInterval(function() {
        playTimer();
        timerStatus = 'playing';
        updateTimerStatus();
      }, 1000);
    } else if(k.which == 82) {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      resetTimer();                              
      updateText();
      timerStatus = 'stopped';
      updateTimerStatus();
    }
  });
  
  function playTimer() {
    if(timerValue > 0) {
      timerValue--;
      updateText();
    }
  }
  
  function resetTimer() {
    timerValue = 24;
  }
  
  function updateText() {
    $timer.html(timerValue);
  }
  
  function updateTimerStatus() {
    $timerStatus.html(timerStatus);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="timerStatus">stopped</div>
<div id="timer">24</div>
```