# Binding arrow keys in jQuery except in input and textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, key-bindings

I found this excellent question about binding the arrow keys with jQuery: [Binding arrow keys in JS/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402698/binding-arrow-keys-in-js-jquery) with a great solution from [Sygmoral](https://stackoverflow.com/users/740813/sygmoral):

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    switch(e.which) {
        case 37: // left
        break;

        case 38: // up
        break;

        case 39: // right
        break;

        case 40: // down
        break;

        default: return; // exit this handler for other keys
    }
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
});
```

**EXCEPT**:  This prevents the arrow keys from working the way they would usually work when the focus is in a text input field.

How would I modify this solution to allow the arrow keys to function normally when the current focus is in an input, text area, or another content editable area?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put this in a condition:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if(!$(e.target).is(':input, [contenteditable]')){
        switch(e.which){
           // the cases as is
        }
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
    }
});
```

Comment: Just to check -- `.is(':input')` covers textareas as well?

Comment: Absolutely! `:input` covers all the input elements including textarea, select, button etc.

Comment: I think the test could be simpler:  `if(!$(e.currentTarget).is(':input,[contenteditable]')){` because `.is()` takes a selector that can have `OR` conditions separated by commas.  Correct?

Comment: Yes! That is way shorter. For the readability i just used such way. Can be done.

Comment: I think it should be `e.target` instead of `e.currentTarget `. The `currentTarget` will always be `document` since that is the element the listener was set to.

Comment: @Titus any issues with `currentTarget`?

Comment: @Titus `currentTarget` has little advantage in such case if you [read the doc here about `currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)

Comment: Yes I've read that and it says `It always refers to the element the event handler has been attached to as opposed to event.target which identifies the element on which the event occurred.` which means that in this case, `currentTarget` will always be the `document`.

Comment: hmm...! This is where i agreed with you. nice catch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use event.target to get the target element of event, so you can check

```
var $target = $(e.target);
if($target.is("input") || $target.is("textarea")) {
    //
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Your editable element may have some common class

```
$('.input').keypress(function(event) {

    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode

    switch(charCode) {
        case 37: // left
        break;

        case 38: // up
        break;

        case 39: // right
        break;

        case 40: // down
        break;

        default: return; // exit this handler for other keys
    }
    e.preventDefault();  
});
```

Comment: That would do the opposite of what I want.   I want to bind the keys to previous and next functionality unless the focus is in an input (where the arrow keys are used for moving the cursor).